# How to Better Handle Redundant Item Renderers components between Desktop and Mobile devices in Flex AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, itemrenderer, flex-mobile

I have an app build with Flex AIR that supports desktop and mobile devices.

Using an Item Renderer for a List components. Have some very common features, the only difference between desktop and mobile clients are the delete button gets triggered differently.

On Mobile I'm listening to a `TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE event`

On Desktop, I will show a delete X mark when mouse hover over the item.

Everything else are the same, it just the way it handle those two actions differently. I don't want to have one Item Rendered for both desktop and mobile, that will cause unnecessary overhead for mobile devices. Hence if have item renderer for each platform then it will cause extra overhead for redundant code in both item renderers.

Any way to avoid the redundant code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but it should work. This just uses a ternary to choose between the two classes using the Capabilities class.

```
<s:List itemRenderer="{ ( Capabilitiles.os.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'ios' ) != -1 || Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'android' ) != -1 ) ? MOBILECLASS : DESKTOPCLASS }" />
```

Alternatively, you could set it in AS3.

```
private function creationCompleteHandler( e:Event ):void {
    if ( Capabilitiles.os.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'ios' ) != -1 || Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'android' ) != -1 ) {
        list.itemRenderer = MobileClass;
    }
    else {
        list.itemRenderer = DesktopClass;
    }
}
```

Again, that is untested. I know I have experienced some odd issues when trying to set the itemRenderer property, so it may not like this. Worth a shot, though.

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't solve my fundamental issue. I already have something similar like this to serve different `itemRenderer` for mobile and desktop. What I interested is to optimize the redundant code between them.

Comment: Right. I misread, sorry about that. Why not create a base class that has everything that the two renderers have in common and then extend that Renderer to add their different features?

Comment: ah, right. Never done such before. I think I got what you mean. Thanks ! Much appreciated

Comment: You basically create your ItemRenderer without the Delete button being shown at all or any functionality to show the delete button. You then create a new Component that is Based On your custom renderer for mobile and desktop. Then all you have to do is add in the code you want to run for each. The base class contains the code both classes need and then the two new classes contain only the code that they need to run.

Comment: From an object oriented programming point of view, removing the redundancy with a base class is a great idea. But be careful, mobile Flex components were optimized for mobile devices. On the web/desktop renderers should extend the `ItemRenderer` class. On mobile, renderers should extend `LabelItemRenderer` or `IconItemRenderer` -- both of which are highly optimized for mobile devices. This may be one area where you don't want to use the same code. Not saying don't do it, but beware of the performance implications.